# Printout SQL Server.mdf table in Index.cshtml

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 I have a class object called table1 with class objects for each column in table1.  I have a working connectionstring tied to testContext in dbContext.  The database has many rows and columns of data and is functioning correctly. In the HomeController the testContext is coupled with the view.  The problem is that the view does not print out the table.

I believe the controller is at fault, line:

```
var dataout = db.Data1.ToList();
```

testContext.cs

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SQLServerMDF.Models
{
    public class testContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Data1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using SQLServerMDF.Models;

namespace SQLServerMDF.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private testContext db = new testContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var dataout = db.Data1.ToList();
           return View(dataout);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SQLServerMDF.Models.Table1>


@section featured {
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <h2>@item.testID @item.datetime  @item.col1 @item.col2 @item.col3</h2>
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. What's the connection string?

Comment: <add name="testContext12" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\folders\SQL\SQL\App_Data\TEST1.mdf;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />